# how to access statistics table (like avg,atdev) value from spotfire boxplot in ironpython

Tags: ironpython, boxplot, spotfire

I have a boxplot with avg,stdev,median statistical measures in the statistical table. I want to use ironpython to export the value for these statistical measures to an external text file. I cant figure out how to access the values of these statistical measures from the Boxplot object in ironpython. Please help.
Is it possible?